# Make multiple copies of files with a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a small shell script that makes the multiple copies of a file. I am able to take the file name as input but not the number of copies. Here is what I wrote. But I am unable to pass the `NUMBER` variable to for loop.

```
echo -n "Enter filename: "
read FILENAME
echo -n "Number of copies to be made: "
read NUMBER
for i in {2..$NUMBER}
do
cp -f $FILENAME ${FILENAME%%.*}"_"$i.csv
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work like that. Bash [performs brace expansion before parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions), so your brace will be expanded before `$NUMBER` is evaluated. See also the [Bash Pitfall #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D), which explains the issue.

One way to do this, using your code, would be:

```
for i in $(eval echo {2..$NUMBER})
do
# ...
done
```

Or, even shorter:

```
for i in $(seq 2 $NUMBER)
# ...
```

(thanks, Glenn Jackman!)

---

Note that typically, [variables should be quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). This is especially important for file names. What if your file is called `foo bar`? Then your `cp -f` would copy `foo` and `bar` since the arguments are split by whitespace.

So, do something like this:

```
cp -f "$FILENAME" "${FILENAME%%.*}_${i}.csv"
```

While it might not matter if your files don't contain whitespace, quoting variables is something you should do automatically to prevent any surprises in the future.

Comment: Thanks man. I am also looking for a concise reference for shell scripting for basic concepts.

Comment: @gthmgeeky Unfortunately (in my opinion) there is no such thing as "basic" concepts for Bash scripts. Bash is very special when it comes to doing things one would assume are rather easy. Check out the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and [Greg's Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) as well as the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/).

Comment: If you want to remove the extension, don't assume the filename has only one dot: use `${FILENAME%.*}` instead of `${FILENAME%%.*}`

Comment: `$(seq 2 $NUMBER)` seems more elegant than `$(eval echo {2..$NUMBER})`

Comment: @glenn True, added that. I just wanted to include the brace expansion to make clear what the problem with the original command was.